# How can I wait for multiple subscriptions?

Tags: rxjs, subscription

I'm trying to make an API call for each element of an array, and emit an specific event if every API response is true.

I was doing the following:

```js
let emit = true

array.forEach(element => {
  this.service.getElement(element).subscribe(loaded => {
      if(!loaded){
         emit = false;
      }
  });
});

this.loaded.emit(emit);
```

But the last line always emits `true`

How can I wait for every request to be resolved before making the output event emission?

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: This isn't an angular question at all. It's an RXJS question

Comment: Sorry @Liam pretty nobbie at this, didn't know the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the last line will always emit `true` because the service code is executed asynchronously. This means that it executes everything except the callback function in the `subscribe` method. This callback function executed once the stream emits a new element. I guess, you are making Http requests to an endpoint here. If so, the callback function is executed for each Http response and the order is not guaranteed.

What you can do is:

```js
forkJoin(
  ...array.map(e => this.service.getElement(e))
).subscribe(responseArray =>
  console.log(responseArray);
  console.log('Complete');
);
```

The callback only executes if all Http response are available. And `responseArray` has the exact same order as the elements in the `array`.

Note: Keep in mind that if you do

```js
let emit = false;
forkJoin(...).subscribe(() => emit = true);
console.log(emit);
```

It would print you false, because the callback executes async. If that seems like strange behaviour for you, I'd highly recommend to read about the JavaScript Eventloop.

Answer (score -1):

Cause call http API is async, so `this.loaded.emit(emit)` executed first;

**fix:**

```
let emit = true

array.forEach(element => {
  this.service.getElement(element).subscribe(loaded => {
      if(!loaded){
         emit = false;
         this.loaded.emit(emit);
      }
  });
});
```

If you want execute `this.loaded.emit(emit)` when all of API response is true, try use `forkJoin`.